# cifs changed behaviour

Tags: permissions, mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I have now for several months mounted my Network share with a line in the fstab . The line used was as follows:

> //192.168.1.1/usb1 /home/mr87/readyshare cifs ,guest,uid=0,gid=0,rw,auto,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

Now, since Saturday, i suddenly had only read permissions on the network share and i had to change it to:

> //192.168.1.1/usb1 /home/mr87/readyshare cifs ,guest,uid=1000,gid=1000,rw,auto,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0

Which means that i now mount the share as my standard user and not as root any more. If i understand correctly what is going on, the first line mounted the share as root and should give all other users all rights to do whatever they like with it over `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777`. But when I now mount it that way my user `mr87` has only read permissions.
When I mount it as `mr87` (`uid=1000, gid=1000`) I own the mount, do have rw-Permissions and can change the permissions of all users. The permissions for "others" are on "read only".

Why this has changed? And why do i have only read permissions although I specified `file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777` when mounting the share as root?

Thanks in foreward

Detzi